# What is the best choice for AI GPU?

Tags: graphics-cards, processor

AI and Deep learning use GPU for speed up their learning process, now the question is what is the best choice for buying Graphic card?
Single GTX1080T on 1 PC or
Double GTX1070T on 1 PC?

Can we use 2 separate PCs for processing?
Any other idea or experience about it?